# change current directory to its windows short path equivalent by one command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm searching a way to change current long name directory to its short name equivalent in one batch command. I've written something like that:

```
C:\Users\Mj\.VirtualBox>for %A in (%cd%) do @echo %~sA
C:\Users\Mj\VIRTUA~1
```

but I do not know how to change directory to the one returned by the echo command. I need to save return value from echo to variable and use

```
cd %shortpath%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the result of your `echo` in a variable you juste have to replace it with a `set`.

So if I use your example it's just something like :

```
C:\Users\Mj\.VirtualBox>for %A in (%cd%) do set shortPath=%~sA
```

And to use it or "print" it :

```
C:\Users\Mj\.VirtualBox>echo %shortPath%
C:\Users\Mj\VIRTUA~1
```

And you can use it as you wish after that.

Hope it will helps !

If you want further explanation feel free to ask I'll try my best to help you :)

**EDIT :**

To change the current directory just after setting the variable.

```
for %A in (%cd%) do (set shortPath=%~sA) && call cd %shortPath%
```

I'm not sure but it looks like the `call` command "waits" for the `for` loop to be done before using the variable.

Feel free to correct me :)

Answer (score -2):

it's so simple. delare a variable of `shortpath`. %cd% returns the path of current working directorty.

`>>C:\Users\HaLF-MenTaL>set shortpath=%cd%`

here is the result.

```
>>C:\Users\HaLF-MenTaL>echo %shortpath%
C:\Users\HaLF-MenTaL
```

and `cd %shortpath%` changes the path.

Hope that i am clear.

Comment: You really should read, and understand a question before attempting to submit an answer.